# Foreign Key from tables that exists in two different DBs on the same server

Tags: database, sybase

In Sybase, is it possible to create a a foreign key from a table in my ARCHIVE database to a Reference Table in my main Database?  You can assume that the databases are both running on the same Sybase Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

See "Using cross-database referential integrity constraints" 
in http://manuals.sybase.com/